# Can not update global variable used in function(Python)

Tags: python, global-variables

I am totally new in python programming language and I try to discover usage of global variables. I wrote a very simple program that consists of two python file as main.py and neuralnetwork.py.Neural network file consist of several class and functions. At this point I would like to call global variable from the function in main.py file.

But unfortunately the related global variables are not being updated when I called them in main file.

**Neuralnetwork.py**

```
import os.path
import numpy as np

IMAGE_H = 0

class initialization(object):

   def parsing(self):

       global IMAGE_H
       IMAGE_H = 25
       print IMAGE_H
```

**Main.py**

```
import sys
from Neuralnetwork import *

def main():

    init=initialization() //class instance
    init.parsing()
    print(IMAGE_H)
```

Basically, I call "IMAGE_H" global variable from Neuralnetwork.py file but as I said before the related global variable is not being updated.

It always shows that IMAGE_H variable is equal to "0" (its initial value) instead of specified "25" in function.The main difference from other questions is to call this global variable from another python file.

How can I properly update this global variable in "initialization" function?

Comment: @Chris_Rands second line(non-empty) in the `main` function: `parsing` is called on the new instance.

Comment: I call it in main file as "init.parsing()" , also should i call it  in NeuralNetwork file?

Comment: You need to call the function within your function in the new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use global variables. You almost never need them in Python, especially as a beginner.

Instead, the class `Initialization` can have a variable `image_h`, like so:

```
class Initialization(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self.image_h = 0

   def parsing(self):
       self.image_h = 25

def main():

    init = Initialization() //class instance
    init.parsing()
    print(init.image_h)
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked succesfully.I apreciated for your help.